# Query is not showing up 0 values mysql

Tags: php, mysql, union, zero

In my query I am listing all of the theater ticket sales and movie ticket sales of different customers. The issue I'm running into is that all of the '0' ticket sales, so those users who haven't boughten a theater ticket or movie ticket is not showing up.

Here's a picture for a visual aspect: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agzj0.png)

I believe I need to be doing a union to return the users who haven't boughten any tickets. I just can't seem to figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code so far:

```
select customer.hippcode, customer.LastName, customer.Firstname, customer.Email,
count(ticketdetails.eventtype) as 'Theater Tickets',
0 as 'Movie Tickets'
from customer
inner join ticketdetails on ticketdetails.hippcode = customer.hippcode
where ticketdetails.hippcode is not null
and ticketdetails.eventType ='T'
Group by Customer.hippcode
union 
select customer.hippcode, customer.LastName, customer.Firstname, customer.Email,
0 as 'Theater Tickets', count(ticketdetails.eventtype) as 'Movie Tickets'
from customer
inner join ticketdetails on ticketdetails.hippcode = customer.hippcode
where ticketdetails.hippcode is not null
and ticketdetails.eventType ='M'
Group by Customer.hippcode
order by `theater tickets` + `movie tickets` desc;
select 
    customer.hippcode, customer.LastName, customer.Firstname, customer.Email,
    sum(case when ticketdetails.eventtype = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) as TheaterTickets,
    sum(case when ticketdetails.eventtype = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as MovieTickets
from customer
inner join ticketdetails on ticketdetails.hippcode = customer.hippcode
where ticketdetails.hippcode is not null
and ticketdetails.eventType in ('T', 'M')
Group by customer.hippcode, customer.LastName, customer.Firstname, customer.Email
Order by 'TheaterTickets' + 'MovieTickets' desc
```

Comment: I think you just need a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

`inner join` => bring the line only if you got a record on both table.

I think you should use a `LEFT JOIN` somewhere to chose the master table

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html and 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the last query is the only one you want.  A `left join` is appropriate, but you need to be careful about the `where` clause:

```
select c.hippcode, c.LastName, c.Firstname, c.Email,
       sum(td.eventtype) as TheaterTickets,
       sum(td.eventtype) as MovieTickets
from customer c left join
     ticketdetails td
    on td.hippcode = c.hippcode and
       td.eventType in ('T', 'M')
Group by c.hippcode, c.LastName, c.Firstname, c.Email
Order by count(t.hippcode) desc;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to read and write.
- Conditions on `ticketdetails` go in the `on` clause, not the `where` clause.
- The condition on `td.hippcode is not null` is unnecessary, because `NULL` will not match in the `join` (note:  you might want to check for the customer column).
- `case` is the standard way to do the conditional sum (and hence correct).  However, MySQL offers a much simpler and intuitive syntax.
- Your order by was doing nothing, because it was adding two strings (hence equivalent to `order by 0`.  Don't use single quotes *ever* for column names, and you won't have a problem like that.